# Properties Transform Lock, not working

Tags: camera, transforms, properties

what is the purpose of these locks?

When I close them I can still change the values.

Is there another way to lock the values??

I'am using 3.3.1

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Those locks are for locking the object when you rotate it or move it with `G` or `R` in the viewport.** Adjusting the values manually works regardless of the locks. For example, if you lock the Z-axis rotation on an object, then you can't rotate it along that axis in the viewport.

Comment: @MontyPike As BlenderMaster15 says, the locks are for locking against manipulation in the viewport - the typical use would be to avoid accidental movement or to make sure you lock it on certain axis/axes without having to remember to press the according key(s). Selecting a field with a value and entering a new one has a lesser potential of accidentally changing something you didn't want to change and not locking this way to enter values leaves the chance to tweak settings intentionally without the need to remove the locking.

Answer (score 0):

don't know can you lock it another way, but you can use some little to bypass this situation. go to the "object constraint properties" and add "copy location", add some one object and add it to the copy location target. now you can't change location of your camera

Comment: It would be nice if it really served the purpose for which the lock icons stand.
In any other software the sliders are also locked. In this case, the numbers in the fields are either grayed out or red.
So that you really can not change anything here.

Comment: @MontyPike Well, might be nice but this is not other software, this is Blender. By the way it's not _any_ other software that works differently, and some software don't even have two ways of changing like a viewport and fields to enter values, so if there is only one method and in that case it wouldn't, _then_ they would be really useless. But since this site is not about changing features, only to help with existing features, we can only tell you how it is. And actually I wouldn't want it differently - I like that I can leave it locked but still alter values if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

On the second part of your question, if there is another way to lock the values: as the other answer states, you can use constraints like *Copy Location*, *Copy Rotation*, *Copy Scale* or even completely *Copy Transforms* but that would require another "dummy object" which itself should be locked somehow in order not to be moved accidentally.

But this is no problem if you make the dummy object unselectable in the outliner or invisible so that you cannot accidentally grab it and do any transforms.

A different solution could be to add keyframes to the properties you don't want to be changed. If you place a single keyframe on a property, no matter on which frame, this property will stay the same. Not completely, you can move sliders, change values etc. (because usually animation keyframes are used to change from time to time), but as soon as you change frames or start a render or whatever, the actual state according to the keyframe is restored.